# How to use Socket.io to update an API live

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, websocket, socket.io

Is it possible to adapt a json from a live api according to the changes in the database?

***server.js***

```
const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once("open", () => {
//Live Stream - Posts 
const observePosr_changes = connection.collection("posts").watch();
    //Observe change in Data Base
    observePosr_changes.on("change", (change) => {
        //console.log('changes right now ->',change);
        switch (change.operationType) {
            //create request
            case "insert":
                //Create posts ->  operationType function
            break;    
            //patch/put request
            case "update":
               //Update posts ->  operationType function 
            break;  
            //delete request
            case "delete":
               //Update posts ->  operationType function 
            break;  
        }
    }); 

});
```

I found using the documentation from mongodb a method by which I can detect live the changes in db atnci when post / patch / delete

***controller/postController.js***

//Create a new post - tahe all value and add into DB

```
exports.createPost = catchAsync(async(req,res)=>{
    const create = await Post.create(req.body);
       res.status(201).json({
            status:"success",
            data:create
            
    });
});
```

//Get Information from DB

```
exports.getAllPosts = catchAsync(async(req,res,next)=>{ 

const getAll = await Post.find()
                         
  res.status(200).json({
    status:"success",
    data:{
        post:getAll
      }
   });
});
```

Is there a possibility to use the socket in this situation to make the application live.
That is, at the moment the mobile application and the website to see the newly added content must refresh.

Answer (score 0):

you want to configure the server first

```
  io = socket(server); -- server : express or any other 
         io.on("connection", function (socket) {
            //console.log("Made socket connection");
        });
```

so you can connect the socket from your client app using unqiue event name

```
this.socket = io.connect(YOUR_URL);
this.socket.on(HERE_YOUR_EVENT_NAME, (data: any) => {
 -- your get the data here 
});
```

when ever you want to send the data to client app emit the data using event name in server side using below code

```
 io.emit(event_name, data);
```

Comment: but in controller directory i must to import socket to use ?? Shoul I do somethink like  const io = require(./server) or something like that.